# Prevent Drupal modules listing

Tags: drupal

Is there any way to prevent drupal modules to be enumerated by eventual attackers
accessing know file locations ie:

http://mysyte.io/sites/all/modules/extlink/README.txt

Comment: Can't you control access through .htaccess files?

Comment: may you please elaborate more ?

Comment: Lots of information about htaccess files if you google, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess